# Find variety of characters in text document

Tags: bash, algorithm, non-ascii-characters

I have a CSV document with 47001 lines in it. Yet when I open it in Excel, there are only 31641 lines.

I know that 47001 is the correct number of lines; it's an export of a database table, whose size I know to be 47001. Additionally: `wc -l my.csv` returns 47001.

So, Excel's parsing fails. I suspect there is some funky control or whitespace character somewhere in this document.

**How do I find out the variety of characters used in some document?**

For example, consider this input file: `ABCAAAaaa\n`.
I would expect the alphabet of characters used in the file to be : `ABCa\n`.

Maybe if we compress it, we can somehow read the [Huffman Tree](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/greedy-algorithms-set-3-huffman-coding/)?

I suspect it will be educational to compare the UTF-8 character variety versus the ASCII character variety. For example: Excel may parse multi-byte characters in ASCII, and thus interpret some bytes as control codepoints.

Comment: Export the Excel table again in the same CSV format as the input.  Compare the result to the original using `diff`.  You might want to send both versions through this first:  `sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]*//g'`  This will strip away all non-alphanumeric characters, so slightly different formats won't matter.

Comment: Do you know how is encoded your `csv`? UTF8? Ascii? ISO-8859-1? UTF16, etc?

Comment: @Alfe sadly Excel's CSV output has reformatted every date and every monetary amount, so the diff regards every line as having changed. However that sed gives me an idea. I was able to remove all alphanumeric characters (plus others that I expected to find in dates or UUIDs): `sed 's/[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\:,\. -\"]*//g' < my.csv | awk '{printf "%s", $1}'`. This left only a small handful of characters: `äãå庆ąäłśธüüã서울ÖüุéøาööåéáéããöÖüüÖãöปèมü市นüãä重ÖÉåäöäôôąåüśีæüàáüüทö`. I can certainly believe some of these might trip up a parser. Doesn't answer the titular question, but it reveals the csv problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here we go if you are on linux (the logic behind could be the same for all but for linux i give the command ) :

```
sed 's/./&\n/g' | sort -u | tr -d '\n'
```

What happend : 
   - First replace all letter by letter followed by "\n" [new line]
   - Then sort all caracter and print uniq occurrences 
   - Remove all the "\n"

Then the input file :

```
ABCAAAaaa
```

will became :

```
A
B
C
A
A
A
a
a
a
```

After sort :

```
a
a
a 
A
A
A
A
B
C
```

Then after uniq :

```
A
B
C
a
```

final output :

```
aABC
```

Comment: How this answers the question: __How do I find out the variety of characters used in some document?__

Comment: Well; that would list all the different characters used in the file. But maybe I've misunderstood the question :x

Comment: Sure. It is clean for the printable `ascii`. But here could be many other "control-characters", (like `\r`) also if the input is utf8-encoded than could be here "combining-marks" and so on... but ok - as starting solution...

Answer (score 1):

You can cut out of the original files some columns which are not likely to be changed by passing the cycle of being parsed and written out again, e. g. a pure text column like a name or a number.  Names would be great.  Then let this file pass the cycle and compare it to the original:

Here's the code:

```
cut -d, -f3,6,8 > columns.csv
```

This assumes that columns 3, 6, and 8 are the name columns and that a comma is the separator.  Adjust these values according to your input file.  Using a single column is also okay.

Now call Excel, parse the file `columns.csv`, write it out again as a csv file `columns2.csv` (with the same separator of course).  Then:

```
diff columns.csv columns2.csv | less
```

A tool like `meld` instead of `diff` might also be handy to analyse the differences.

This will show you which lines experienced a change by the →parse→dump cycle.  Hopefully it will affect only the lines you are looking for.